# How can we capture test case results if we use Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

What are the possible ways to report or capture the result?

Or should we keep on staring at the screen when the automation script runs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use JUnit. It provides output.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the test report using `testng`.

First install testng by following this [link](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/install-testng/)

After installation of testng, write some test cases in a class using `@Test`
annotation. Then click on run and run as a testng test. Then refresh your project and in test-output folder, you will find the testng report.
If you google, you will find a lots of links about this.

You can go through this [link](http://learn-automation.com/generate-reports-selenium-using-testng-xslt/)

Answer (score 1):

Selenium (like other browser automation frameworks) is most commonly used to write automated acceptance tests within a test framework such as [Cucumber-JVM](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm). I mention Cucumber-JVM since it's designed for acceptance testing and is the most common such framework used with Java applications, but you could use JUnit or TestNG or another test framework if you wanted.

In any such framework, within each test, Selenium or another browser driver simulates user actions in the UI and statements written in the test framework's API/DSL assert that the expected result occurred. The test framework runs all of the tests and reports any which failed.

It is still often useful to watch the screen while debugging a failing test, however.

Answer (score 0):

you can take screenshots of the screens, then you can create PDF's/doc's if you need. to capture screenshot you the command

```
screenShotImage = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

use screenShotImage.getAbsolutePath() to get file path.

Answer (score 0):

Test results are always linked to project needs, i have seen scenarios where test results should be in PDF.

Here are some suggestions on test results

1. Extent reports - This is the java library contains graphs as well as
   detailed steps. This even allows screenshots
2. If you are using TestNG or Junit, it has default reporting. However if you are looking for more advanced graphical report, use 
   [RealTimeReport](https://github.com/startingwithseleniumwebdriver/RealTimeReport)
3. if you link the results in documentation, create a custom report code